# Using Chebyshev Inequality to find lower bound of an interval

Tags: probability, statistics

Given a random variable $X$ with $\mu = 200$ and $\sigma = 10$. Find a lower bound for $P(130 \leq X \leq 270)$ using Chebyshev Inequality.

What I've tried was:

The inequality is $P(|X - E[X]| \geq k\sigma) \leq \frac{1}{k^2}$, so for $P(130 \leq X \leq 270)$ we have $P(|X-200| \geq 700) \leq \frac{1}{70^2} = P(|X-220| \leq 700) \geq 1 - \frac{1}{70^2} = P(|X-200| \leq 700) \geq 0.9997$

But in the solutions the answer is $\frac{48}{49} = 0.98$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You accidentally turned $70$ into $700$ and so $7 \sigma$ into $70 \sigma$.  Note that $\frac{48}{49}=1-\frac1{7^2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $P(130 \leq X \leq 270) = P(|X-200| \leq \color{blue}{ 70})$. Just solve the inequality or insert the bounds.

And therefore $P(|X - E[X]| \leq k\sigma) \geq 1- \frac{1}{k^2}\Rightarrow P(|X-200| \leq 70) \geq 1-\frac{1}{7^2}=\frac{49-1}{49}=\frac{48}{49}$